# Search Directory for folders

Tags: batch-file, search, directory

I am trying to create a batch file that I can use to type in a name of a folder and search multiple directories, then display the results in a new window. Example: I want to search for "tcash" in 3 separate directories, ie; \vm-xa01\users, vm-xa02\users and vm-xa03\users. How can I do this?

Comment: Hello! Try to post some code showing what you have tried so far, then community members will find it easier to help you.

Comment: To be honest, I am a very beginner in code. I am not sure all the way.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6

Comment: is that a file name, a _partial_ file name, or a dir name?

Comment: tcash would be the exact name I am looking for.

Comment: I am editing post to remove Powershell tag as he clearly asked for batch help

Answer (score 0):

The original question had Powershell tag, so the answer is Powershell. For cmd (batch) script, I'd strongly suggest you to move into Powershell anyway. It's 2018 and cmd scripts require lots of tweaking.

In Powershell, there's a built-in cmdlet `Out-GridView` that might be suitable. For example, to display all txt files in c:\some\path and its subdirectories requires just a few commands. Like so,

```
gci c:\some\path -Recurse | ? { $_.extension -eq ".txt" } | ogv
```

First off, get a recursive list of all files

```
gci c:\some\path -Recurse
```

Then select those that have extension .txt

```
| ? { $_.extension -eq ".txt" }
```

Finally, pass the results to out-gridview aka ogv

```
| ogv
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think PowerShell is the better script  language for your task.

You can do a dir/Get-ChildItem with ranges `[1-3]` similar to a Regular Expression, so:

```
Get-ChildItem "\vm-xa0[1-3]\users\tcash" -File -Recurse | Out-Gridview
```

should enumerate all matching files and display in a gui window.